# Efficiently comparing lists of arbitrarily-assigned labels

Tags: python, algorithm, list, comparison

I have two lists of item labels (from clustering) which represent the same items, but have different (arbitrary) labels assigned to them. An example:

```
labels1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]
labels2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0]
```

The structure is the same in each list so the clusters found are identical apart from their labels. They can both be converted to the following list by renaming the labels in the order that they first appear.

```
renamed = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

What I'm looking for is a way of checking for this property, so the problem reduces to finding an efficient way of doing the relabelling in the `relabel` function below.

```
labels1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]
labels2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0]

def relabel(labels):
    """Rename list of labels to the order they first appear in the list.
    """
    seen = []
    renamed = []
    for l in labels:
        if l not in seen:
            seen.append(l)
        renamed.append(seen.index(l))
    return renamed

assert relabel(labels1) == relabel(labels2)
```

What I have works, I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this comparison that I'm missing. For example if the list is large would using a generator expression help?

Comment: A generator expression would help as you can stop comparison of two lists earlier in case of mismatch and do not need to convert everything up to the end.

Comment: What I have works <-- Hmm, I doubt that. Your function does not return anything.

Comment: Good spot - forgot to put that back in after experimenting with a generator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original function does not return a result, I am surprised that you say it works. There are a few things we can optimize here:

- We will use a dictionary `seen` instead of a list, because `list.index` is costly with O(n)
- `seen` will map items to their new name, which is just the current length of the dictionary - but `len` is less costly with O(1). Also `x in some_dict` is O(1)  as well compared to O(n) for `x in some_list`.
- lastly, we will rewrite your function as a generator and check for equality of two relabels in a generator expression with `all` and `izip`. `all` will stop at the first mismatch.

Here's the code:

```
from itertools import izip

def relabel(labels):
    seen = {}
    for l in labels:
        if l not in seen:
            seen[l] = len(seen)
        yield seen[l]

def compare_labels(l1,l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False

    l1 = relabel(l1)
    l2 = relabel(l2)
    return all(x==y for x,y in izip(l1,l2))
```

*edit*: I just realized that just using `izip` instead of `izip_longest` and to check the length upfront is better. If it is assured that two labels you pass to `compare_labels` are always of the same length, you can leave this check out.

Comment: I did consider a dictionary but couldn't see a simple way, so I really like your `seen[l] = len(seen)`

Comment: @JamieBull updated my answer a little. The advantage of `izip` or `izip_longest` is that it will return a generator as well.

Comment: Checking length upfront may not be possible and may by ineffective (l1, l2 do not need to be lists after all). I think your previous solution with `izip_longest` was more general :)

Comment: @PatrykObara Well I guess it depends. Checking the length is very fast because lists store their length internally and the problem statement clearly specifies that the labels are lists. Now, when two lists are of different length the comparison with `izip_longest` might do a lot of unnecessary comparisons. If the algorithm has to be more general then checking the length upfront might not be possible, but that is not what was asked for here.

Answer (score 2):

I see two things that can be improved. First, since you're using a `list` for the seen labels, the `l not in seen` and `seen.index(l)` operations take `O(n)` time. Instead of a `list`, you can use a `dict`.

Then, as you suggested yourself, instead of returning a list, you can return a generator with the `yield` keyword.

```
def relabel(labels):
    """
    Rename list of labels to the order they first appear in the list.
    """
    seen = dict()
    for l in labels:
        if l not in seen:
            seen[l] = len(seen)
        yield seen[l]

assert all(x == y for x, y in zip(relabel(labels1), relabel(labels2)))
```

Comment: This will fail if the lists are the same except one has extra items on the end. @timgeb's answer with `izip_longest` avoids that.

Comment: Indeed, but this is unnecessary if you know that both lists are the same length. And it would also be more efficient to check for the length before if this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to above answers - you don't need to do relabeling twice, nor you do not need to go through whole lists (you can stop on first mismatch). If goal is to verify this property, then:

```
 def verify(labels1, labels2):
     seen = {}
     used = {}
     for (x, y) in izip_longest(labels1, labels2):
         if x == None or y == None: return False
         if seen.has_key(x):
             if seen[x] != y: return False
         else:
             if used.has_key(y): return False
             seen[x] = y
             used[y] = True
     return True
```

This algorithm works in O(min(len(labels1), len(labels2))) and it uses O(num(labels1) + num(labels2)) memory.

If set of labels is finite (and preferably small), then you can speed up looking up value in `used` set by using bit operations (this does not change asymptotic speed, but may result in large gains in practice).

Comment: "I addition to above answers - you don't need to do relabeling twice, nor you do not need to go through whole lists" <-- the other answers don't do any of that. They are using generators to explicitly avoid what you describe.

Comment: In both answers relabel is called twice - those solutions generate third list and compare that, my solution looks for first mismatch (without generating additional list)). Difference is small, but it's there - you don't need two maps, only one map and one set; set operations can be faster than map operations.

Comment: Generators are irrelevant to algorithm; for python - yes, there's no difference, but in other language you can avoid having two dicts in certain cases. This may give you significant performance boost for small sets of labels.